# Retrieve object from URL in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is for a school project, and I don't really understand exactly what I'm supposed to do, so I'll explain what the teacher told me and what I did so far, hope you guys can help.
To examine the success of a program, the teacher wants to manually add a number to the url of the page.
I need to take that number, extract it from the url, then implant it in a method so that it will decrypt a message with the same ID number (I have no idea how he intends to do it or activate said method).
Here is what I wrote:
In the DataModel:

```
public static void GetMessage (int? MesNum, out string MesSuc)
{
    SqlConnection cnctn = new SqlConnection(cnctnstrng);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = cnctn;
    cmd.CommandText = "GetMessage";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LineNum", SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlDataReader rd;
    try
    {
        cnctn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters["@LineNum"].Value = MesNum;
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        byte[] Message = (byte[])rd["MessageText"];
        if (Message != null)
        {
            MesSuc = chat.Models.DomainModels.Security.DecryptStringFromBytes(Message);
        }
        else
        {
            MesSuc = "Unable to decrypt Message";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MesSuc = "Unable to decrypt Message";
    }
    finally
    {
        cnctn.Close();
    }
}
```

In the Controller:

```
public ActionResult singlmsgdecrptn()
        {
            string MesSuc;
            chat.Models.DataModels.userdbmanip.GetMessage(*?*, out MesSuc);
            return View(MesSuc);
        }
```

The *?* is where the number is supposed to come in.
In the View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>singlmsgdecrptn</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @ViewBag.MesSuc
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default routing for MVC takes and ID optional parameter.  Check the RouteConfig.cs in the App_Start folder.

So you should just be able to add it as a parameter to your controllers action result.

```
public ActionResult singlmsgdecrptn(int? id)
        {
            string MesSuc;
            chat.Models.DataModels.userdbmanip.GetMessage(id, out MesSuc);
            return View(MesSuc);
        }
```

Also, not sure why you're using a nullable int here, but I followed suit.  Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Ok, so now I just manually add a number to the end of the url? And if I press enter it should start the method?

Comment: Oh and I'm using a nullable int because that's what the teacher told me to do, in case he won't write anything or something. Really, I have no idea what he wants me to do.

So what do I need to change in the url to make it work?

Comment: Yes, adding {controllerName}/singlmsgdecrptn/{id} would call your method supplying the id to the variable.  Using a nullable int means that this method will be called whether they provide an int or not(null) in the URL string.  Assuming you don't have another method with the same name not requiring one.  So if there is no ID value entered the method will still run and supply a null to the GetMessage method.  I can't say if this is incorrect or not as I don't know what the outcomes should be.